# Joining two lines based on specific characters Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to join lines of data information in Notepad ++, currently, the data looks like this:

It has the above format for about 100,000 rows. I want to combine row 1 with row 2, but sometimes row 2 and row 3 combine and look something like this:

I want the output to look like this (all on one line):

I tried using this formula:

SEARCH: `(.+)\R(.+)`

REPLACE: `\1 \2`

Comment: You need to tell us which 'special characters' you are talking about, otherwise we have to guess, and that's not helping you. Also give example of input that doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks for the push, edited, hope that's a bit more useful.

Comment: I think you have a problem in you inout text, not having the format you expect, Try inspecting your input, for instance, is '10546  ABC DEF' always present at every other line.

Comment: " I want to combine row 1 with row 2, but sometimes row 2 and row 3" but what are the conditions of join in each case?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52916592/edit) and add some inputs lines **and** expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match specific characters in Regex, you can simply type that character. for example, `apple` will only match apple. If you want to match a number, you can use `\d`. This will match 8, but not d.

If you want to match only things that end in 4 numbers separated by a dot, try this one: `\n(.*?\d\d\.\d\d)\n`

An explanation for each part can be found [here](https://regexr.com/41kme).